# Monitoring file changes on a redirected My Documents folder

Tags: vb.net, windows

I have a small utility application written in VB.NET that allow my customers to edit files (MS Word mostly) from our web application.  The application downloads and stores files being edited temporarily in the user's My Documents folder.  Once editing is complete, the utility sends the file back to our web server.

The utility monitors the file lock that is established by MS Word.  Once the lock is removed, it knows editing is complete.

This works great, with the exception of customers that use redirected My Document folders.  There seems to be a delay from when the lock is removed and the file is updated.  Therefore, sometimes the file we grab does not contain the modifications.

It appears the Windows folder redirection may be synchronizing these files between a cache and/or offline copy.  Is that correct?

If so, is there any other way to determine if the updates have been committed to the file?  Sometime, users do not make any changes, but we still need to communicate that editing is finished to the web server.  SO, monitoring the save time-stamp does not work.

Any advice or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, the Windows offline copy functionality is on by default.  (And IIRC it will sometimes be on for redirected folders even if it is otherwise off.  Sorry, I don't remember the details.)  But I'm not sure exactly why the lock would be on the wrong file / why you'd be copying the wrong file.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you read the file using the same handle you use to monitor the file lock?

Comment: The application does not grab the file from the same handle that it monitors the lock with, that has been an issue.  However, I'm not sure that would solve this problem.  In this situation, it seems like not having the lock would give the synchronization some time to update the file.  If the lock prevented it, wouldn't that always make the file incorrect?

Comment: I don't know how offline copies and network locking interact.  The problem might not even be the offline copies, but just the fact that the file is on the network.